Livewire 3: Are model properties locked by default in a form object?
The documentation says that componenet model properties are locked by default. Is this the same for model properties in form objects?
Eloquent models and locking
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties#eloquent-models-and-locking
I don't know how to work with dev tool console to manipulate this property and test if it can be changed from the front end.

question answered: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/8277
